# git via ssh to Github fails in Virtualbox

Tags: git, ssh, virtualbox

I have Archlinux installed in my Virtualbox hosted by Windows 7.

I generated my ssh key taking the steps as follows:

```
1. ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "my@gmail.com";
2. copy and add id_rsa.pub to Github;
3. ssh -T git@github.com
```

What I got:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.131)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ##############.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 
Host key verification failed.
```

Does ssh from Virtualbox matter here?

---

SOLVED: I should have typed YES literally instead of just pressing ENTER.

Thanks to @michas for help.

Comment: Oops, I typed "yes", and it says "Host key verification failed." @michas

Comment: Any hints with `ssh -vvv ...` ?

Comment: It shows:   OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013  ||
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/me/.ssh/config   ||
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config   ||
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0   ||
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ...: Name or service not known

Comment: Please add this to the question for readable formatting. Oh, and I did not mean the `...` literal. Use `ssh -vvv -T git@github.com`.

Comment: @michas, sorry, I just realized that I actually didn't TYPE yes, "literally". I just pressed Enter which I mistakenly took as a default. It is embarrassing that I stumbled over this for more than one hour.